# Por que no reconoce el metodo?

Tags: c#

Hice un método operaciones con 2 parámetros de salida puse que sea public void pero al querer escribir el nombre del método no me aparece y me sale error

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        operaciones(15,20,out int v1,out int v2);
        Console.WriteLine($"Suma{v1} Resta{v2}");
    }

public void operaciones(int x,int y, out int v1,out int v2)
    {
        v1 = x + y;
        v2 = x - y;
    }
```

Comment: si tu metodo esta en la misma clase que tu main, debes colocar tu metodo como static

Answer (score 2):

`operaciones` es un método de instancia. Está asociado a un objeto, una instancia de la clase que has tenido que crear previamente; pongamos que la clase se llama Zeiker:

```
Zeiker zeiker = new Zeiker();
zeiker.operaciones(15, 20, out int v1, out int v2);
```

Desde `operaciones`, se puede invocar a otro método de instancia directamente porque asume que estás usando la misma instancia.

```
public void operaciones2() {
}

public void operaciones(int x,int y, out int v1,out int v2)
{
    v1 = x + y;
    v2 = x - y;
    operaciones2();
}
```

pero `Main` no es un método de instancia, es un método estático y se ejecuta desde fuera del contexto de un objeto.

La solución es que en `Main` tienes que crear una instancia del objeto para llamar al método, como se muestra en el primer fragmento de código.

PS: En futuras preguntas, sería mejor si fueras más específico y añadas **el mensaje de error que te da el compilador o el IDE.**